# Jquery .on and .off is not working with mouseenter and mouseleave events

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am trying to play with `jQuery` `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events but failing.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
$("#selector").mouseenter(function(){
        some code....
        jQuery(this).off('mouseenter'); 
    }
);
$("#selector").mouseleave(function(){
    some code....
    jQuery(this).on('mouseenter');
});
```

In this `.off()` is working but unfortunately `.on` is not working.

Can anyone help me here?

Thx in advance.

> > >

Edit:
Sorry for less information in my above question.

I need to open tooltip on `mouseenter` and have some buttons in that tooltip. This tooltip is appended in same div. So when I try to click on button in the tooltip it calls `mouseenter` event and so tooltip is appended again in the div. 
So I am calling `.off()` event once tooptip is called till mouse doesn't leave selector.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thx again.

Comment: you are not passing a function to `.on`... Furthermore, what you are trying to do is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind the event to a handler. `$(this).on('mouseenter');` will not bind any handler to it.

Try using a function to bind as handler so it can be bounded again and instead of `on` and `off` use `.one`

```
$("#selector").one('mouseenter', selMouseEnter);

$("#selector").mouseleave(function(){
    some code....
    $("#selector").one('mouseenter', selMouseEnter);
});

function selMouseEnter () {
    some code....
}
```

**Edit:** what you are trying to do can be achieved using `.hover` or simply implementing `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` functions. No need to `bind/unbind` as these function called once on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

The `on` and `off` methods are not used to turn events on and off, they are used to bind and unbind events.

So, this:

```
$("#selector").mouseenter(function(){
  some code....
});
```

does the same as:

```
$("#selector").on("mouseenter", function(){
  some code....
});
```

and:

```
$("#selector").bind("mouseenter", function(){
  some code....
});
```

You don't have to unbind the event while the mouse is over the element, just handle the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
$("#selector").mouseenter(function(){
  some code....
}).mouseleave(function(){
  some code....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can simply be achieved with:

```
$("#selector").mouseenter(function(){
    some code....
}).mouseleave(function(){
    some code....
});
```

There is no rebinding and unbinding required.

Also, you are using `.on` wrong, you need to pass a function as well. See [`.on` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) .